# setup ordering in priority blocking queue

Tags: java, algorithm, priority-queue, comparable, blockingqueue

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue` in which I am adding `SocketHolder` as shown below. And let's say current datacenter where this code is running is `abc`. We have three datacenters `abc`, `def` and `pqr`.

```
private static final PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketHolder> liveQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();

for (SocketHolder socket : listOfSockets) {
    liveQueue.add(socket);
}
```

Now what I need to do is:

- I have to setup some sort of ordering on `liveQueue` so that all `SocketHolder` whose datacenter is `abc` (which is current datacenter where the code is running), they should be at the top so which means when we retrieve it from this `liveQueue` all `SocketHolder` with `abc` datacenter should come out first and then later on all other `SocketHolder` with other dc's. Similarly for cases where current datacenter is either `pqr` or `def`.

Below is my `SocketHolder` class that implements Comparable interface but I am confuse what I need to do in my `compareTo` method so that at the top of `liveQueue` (after adding elements to it) we have all `SocketHolder` whose datacenter are current datacenter and then followed by other datacenter in which I have no priority.

```
public final class SocketHolder implements Comparable<SocketHolder> {
  private final Socket socket;
  private final Datacenter dc;
  private final Context context;

  public SocketHolder(Socket socket, Datacenter dc, Context context) {
    super();
    this.socket = socket;
    this.dc = dc;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(SocketHolder o) {
    // String currentDC = Utils.CURRENT_DATACENTER.get().name();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would just use a different queue for the current data center and process it first. PQ is overkill for this, as there appear to be essentially only two priorities: 'this' and 'other'.

Comment: A PQ has the advantage that if a 'late' task is submitted, it will immediately bubble to the top.

Comment: @IanMc Only if you processes the queues unintelligently,  or there are more than two priority levels. You should take from the first queue first and if empty take *one* item from the second queue: rinse and repeat. A PQ will also lose order of insertion if there are only two priorities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The live datacenter will be assigned priority 1, and the other datacenters priority 2.  The queue will process the lowest priority first.

```
public final class SocketHolder implements Comparable<SocketHolder> {
   private final Socket socket;
   private final Datacenter dc;
   private final Context context;
   private final int priority;

   public SocketHolder(Socket socket, Datacenter dc, Context context) {
      super();
      this.socket = socket;
      this.dc = dc;
      this.context = context;
      this.priority = this.dc.getName().equals(Utils.CURRENT_DATACENTER.get().name()) ? 1 : 2;
   }

   @Override
   public int compareTo(SocketHolder o) {
       return Integer.compare(this.priority, o.priority);
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of giving each dc a number why can't we do this basis on current datacenter that we already know of and datacenter for which `SocketHolder` we are adding?

Comment: I mean just check current datacenter (code is already there in my compareTo method but it is commented) with datacenter of SocketHolder we are adding and basis on that do the ordering? Will this not work?

Comment: Yes - How does the SocketHolder object know which is the current datacenter?

Comment: By just making this call `String currentDC = Utils.CURRENT_DATACENTER.get().name();` This will tell what's the current datacenter where the code is running so we can use that and compare it and that's what I mentioned I believe in my question.

Comment: I don't know the method to get the DC name ... assuming it is getName()